# Attempted to load class "Thread" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?

Tags: php, multithreading, symfony

### Description:

Created a php class ChildThread that extends Thread. It looks something like this:

```
use Thread;

class ChildThread extends Thread
{
    public $data;
    private $anonymous_func;
    public function __construct($anonymous_func)
    {
        $this->anonymous_func = $anonymous_func;
    }

    public function run(){
        $func = $this->anonymous_func;
        $this->data = $func();
    }
}
```

### Problem:

I'm getting this following error:

> Attempted to load class "Thread" from the global namespace. Did you
>   forget a "use" statement?

I clearly have a `use` statement, which uses the correct class:

```
/**
 * When the start method of a Thread is invoked, the run method code will
 * be executed in separate Thread, asynchronously.<br/>After the run method
 * is executed the Thread will exit immediately, it will be joined with
 * the creating Thread at the approriate time.
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php
 */
class Thread extends Threaded implements Traversable, Countable, ArrayAccess {
  /** class code here **/
}
```

### Question:

Why is it saying that I need to have a "use" statement, when I'm already using one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) extension, that provides these classes. It is not installed by default in PHP Core, since it requires a thread-safe version of PHP. Indeed, PHP does not come in a thread-safe version in the standard distribution.

You can have PHP with ZTS enabled (*Zend Thread Safety*) by fetching PHP's sources, and [compiling it with a special flag](http://php.net/manual/fr/pthreads.requirements.php). For Windows, direct downloads are also available.

I recommend you to have a normal version of PHP for your web applications ([which can't use threads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads#user-content-sapi-support)), and a hand-compiled ZTS version for your CLI applications (daemons, etc).

Once you have that ZTS version of PHP, you can install pthreads via PECL, or install it manually (that's way easier than compiling PHP correctly ;) ).